Why the unbound DNS failed to dig a domain?
This is a follow-up question to my earlier question. Below is the /etc/unbound/unbound.conf file:
# unbound.conf(5) config file for unbound(8).
server:
    directory: "/etc/unbound"
    username: "unbound"
    chroot: ""
    logfile: "/etc/unbound/unbound.log"
    pidfile: "/etc/unbound/unbound.pid"
    verbosity: 1
    # listen on all interfaces and answer queries from the local port 3000.
    interface: 0.0.0.0 
    interface: ::0
    port: 3000
    access-control: 10.0.0.0/8 allow
    #access-control: 2001:DB8::/64 allow

With unbound.service started, I tried to dig a domain via the local unbound server:
root@DNS:/etc/unbound# dig example.com A @192.168.1.50 -p 3000

; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.24.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com A @192.168.1.50 -p 3000
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 8367
;; flags: qr rd ad; QUERY: 0, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.50#3000(192.168.1.50) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 29 16:18:19 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 12

I don't understand why  WARNING: recursion requested but not available as unbound is configured to be a recursive resolver by default. Also. SERVER: 192.168.1.50#3000(192.168.1.50) (UDP) shows that unbound was used, however, it failed to get the domain. What is wrong and how do I fix this issue?
Below shows the answer via systemd-resolved.service stub server:
root@DNS:/etc/unbound# dig example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.24.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 36356
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        3304    IN  A   93.184.215.14

;; Query time: 12 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 29 16:43:59 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56

Update:
After correcting the subnet as mentioned by @mpboden answer, the dig command only worked once. Why is this the case?
root@DNS:/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d# systemctl start unbound.service
root@DNS:/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d# [1730230920] unbound[5780:0] notice: init module 0: subnetcache
[1730230920] unbound[5780:0] notice: init module 1: validator
[1730230920] unbound[5780:0] notice: init module 2: iterator
[1730230921] unbound[5780:0] info: start of service (unbound 1.19.2).

root@DNS:/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d# dig example.com A @192.168.1.50 -p 3000

; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.24.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com A @192.168.1.50 -p 3000
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40273
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        3600    IN  A   93.184.215.14

;; Query time: 712 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.50#3000(192.168.1.50) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 29 19:42:34 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56

root@DNS:/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d# dig google.com A @192.168.1.50 -p 3000

; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.24.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> google.com A @192.168.1.50 -p 3000
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 49774
;; flags: qr rd ad; QUERY: 0, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.50#3000(192.168.1.50) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 29 19:42:56 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 12


root@DNS:/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d# dig example.com A @192.168.1.50 -p 3000

; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.24.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com A @192.168.1.50 -p 3000
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 46236
;; flags: qr rd ad; QUERY: 0, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.50#3000(192.168.1.50) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 29 19:43:36 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 12


What's your end goal exactly? Do you just want to add a few names that should be resolved by Unbound then forward all other queries to other resolvers? Do you want to handle a whole zone? Something else?

I think mpboden has it right though, if no tange matches the origin IP by default Unbound denies the query. So if the origin IP is in the 192.168.1.0/24 range, with just 10.0.0.0/8 allowed anything else wil be denied.

@kos At the moment, trying to get the minimum configuration for unbound.conf as mentioned documentation to work. Learning how to use unbound. Thereafter, I plan to configure unbound to forward all local requests to an external DNS and retrieve the ip to pass back to respective clients in LAN.

I see that you defined the following:
access-control: 10.0.0.0/8 allow
But your subnet is 192.168.1.0/24. Change this line to:
access-control: 192.168.1.0/24 allow
This will allow unbound to accept DNS queries from the 192.168.1.0/24 network.

I stopped and disabled the unbound.service, changed the subnet, started the service and ran the dig command. It worked the first time but not the subsequent time. Why is this the case? I have updated my question to show this issue.

@SunBear Starting/Stopping a service is different than Enabling/Disabling a service. Starting/Stopping does just that...it either Starts or Stops a service. On the other hand, Enabling/Disabling has to do with whether the service runs at boot. If you want Unbound to start at boot, then the service needs to be Enabled. Then don't disable it again unless you don't want it to start at boot. Moving forward, any configuration changes to Unbound can simply be accepted by restarting the service with sudo systemctl restart unbound.

@SunBear I can't explain why Unbound would work on the first query but not subsequent queries. The only thing that comes to mind is the service was not running after your first query. Anyway, Unbound is very easy to install and setup. I saw your other question, and it seems that you had a difficult time for some reason. Perhaps you should visit the Unbound official documentation and go through their setup/configuration for a basic Resolver for Home Network.

Unbound is working again. Yes, I was learning via Unbound documentation. The minimum config unbound.conf file came from Unbound.  Really appreciate your help.

I have added a few more attributes based on the basic Resolver for Home Network link you have provided. I can't allow remote-control. I have posted my issue here. Can you advise on how to resolve it?
